# Android image picker ImageView not working

Tags: android, android-imageview, bitmapfactory

MY android app hangs the moment I select the picture ,there are no exception and I can't understand why,please help the code is below

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
public class SelectPhoto extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.photopick_layout);
        Button btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.clickme);

        btn.setOnClickListener(this);


    }

     public void onClick(View arg0) {
           // TODO Auto-generated method stub
           Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
             android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
           startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
          }

     @Override
     protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub

      super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
      TextView textTargetUri = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.targeturi);
      if (resultCode == RESULT_OK){
       Uri targetUri = data.getData();
       textTargetUri.setText(targetUri.toString());
       Intent mi = new Intent(this , ImgDisplay.class);
       mi.putExtra(getString(R.string.app_name),targetUri);
       startActivity(mi);

      }

     }
     }
```

**Imagedisplay Activity** this is the part where it should display the selected image form its uri

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class ImgDisplay extends Activity {
    private String a;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.image_display);

 a =getIntent().getStringExtra(getString(R.string.app_name));




 Uri myUri = Uri.parse(a);

 ImageView b=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_view);
 Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(a);
 b.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(a));
 b.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);



    }

}
```

**photo pick layout** this is the first layout where it asks you to select the image from the gallary

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:background="#00AEC5">

    <RelativeLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:id="@+id/btn2"
>

    <TextView
  android:id="@+id/targeturi"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  />

 <Button android:id="@+id/clickme" 
 android:text="@string/pick" 
 style="@style/style1"
android:layout_centerInParent="true"
 ></Button>


  </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**Image_display layout* this is the layout to display the image

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:background="#00AEC5">

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/image_view"     
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
  android:adjustViewBounds="true"  
  android:maxWidth="42dp"  
  android:maxHeight="42dp"  
  android:scaleType="fitCenter"  
  android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"  

  ></ImageView>
</LinearLayout>
```

I'm sure that this is pretty easy but I'm new to this

Answer (score 0):

You should check for requestCode in onActivityResult (example [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html)), handle the result if it belongs to your request and call super only if it does not.

Answer (score 0):

use

> Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT

instead. Here is my image picker code that works perfectly .

```
public class GalleryActivity extends Activity {

static Bitmap bmp;
ImageView GalImg;
Uri imageUri;
protected static final int PHOTO_PICKED = 0;
// values for scaling image
    protected int outputX = 320;
    protected int outputY = 480;
    protected int aspectX = 2;
    protected boolean scale = true;
    protected int aspectY = 3;
    Bundle extra;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.i("gal", "oncreate");
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //setContentView(R.layout.gallery_screen);
     extra = getIntent().getExtras();
    Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    photoPickerIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");
    photoPickerIntent.putExtra("aspectX", aspectX);
    photoPickerIntent.putExtra("aspectY", aspectY);
    photoPickerIntent.putExtra("outputX", outputX);
    photoPickerIntent.putExtra("outputY", outputY);
    photoPickerIntent.putExtra("scale", scale);
    File photo = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");      
    photoPickerIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photo));
    imageUri = Uri.fromFile(photo);
    photoPickerIntent.putExtra("outputFormat", Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG.toString());
    photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
    startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, PHOTO_PICKED);

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultcode, 
        Intent intent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultcode, intent);
    Log.i("gal", "onActivity");
    if (requestCode == 0) {

        if (intent != null && resultcode == RESULT_OK) {
            Log.i("gal", "if request ok");
            //Uri selectedImage = intent.getData();// fetching uri of selected image                                                        // image


            //Bitmap bMap = (Bitmap) intent.getExtras().get("data");

            /*String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };// string data of image                                                                            // containing

            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            // The cursor query returns with the path, but you don't know
            // which column it's in until you use the columnIndex code.
            // That simply gets the number of the column based on its name,
            // the same one used in the filtering process.
            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            String filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);// file path of image

            cursor.close();//Closes the Cursor, releasing all of its resources 


            bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);*/

            //saving this bitmap into static photo which will have camera pic if camera is called otherwise gallery 
            //is selected and gallery image gets saved in it

            //PlayMenuActivity.photo=bmp;========
            //PlayMenuActivity.photo=bMap;


             Uri selectedImage = imageUri;
             getContentResolver().notifyChange(selectedImage, null);                
             ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
             Bitmap bitmap;
             try {
                 bitmap = android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(cr, selectedImage);  
                 PlayMenuActivity.photo=bitmap;
                 Log.i("gal",String.valueOf(bitmap));
                 Log.i("photo", "data.getAction() is not null. setting image.");

             } catch (Exception e) {
                 //Toast.makeText(this, "Failed to load", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                 Log.i("photo", e.toString());
             }

            Intent i=new Intent(GalleryActivity.this,ShowActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("category","gallery");
            startActivity(i);



        } else {
            Log.i("Status:", "Photopicker canceled");
        }

    }
}
```

Hope this helps .

Comment: Thanks all ,I'm sure all of the codes above works just fine,but I'm in a learning phase now so I need to know where did I go wrong,otherwise I'll keep using ready written codes and never learn to write on my own,I found stuff that could do the same thing for me,anyhow,if anybody could detect the error for me I'd be really happy  Please

Answer (score 0):

Ok thank you everybody I know its shameful but the only problem was that I forgot to include the "ImgDisplay" Activity in the manifest file :) otherwise the code is working just fine :D